# How to write INSERT IF NOT EXISTS queries in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am connecting two databases for data migration. I want to check whether a record from the table of the first database exists in the second database.

I.e. from the source database user table I want to migrate data to destination database user table.

How to write query using if not exists?

Comment: Which version of standard SQL? `Merge` is standard SQL but not supported by all RDBMss

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into myTable
select * from myOldTable ot
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from mytable t where t.ID = ot.ID)
```

You might be better writing it as a join

```
insert into myTable
select ot.*
from myOldTable ot
LEFT JOIN mtTable t
ON ot.ID = t.ID
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

or depending on your database, a merge might be better, there are lots of options

Comment: The possibility of race conditions exists with both these so the OP would need a unique constraint or additional locking hints.

Comment: @Martin, you are right, adding `WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)` should resolve that problem i believe

Comment: Actually just noticed Andomar's point that this is for a data migration so the OP may well not need to worry about this.

Answer (score 3):

I find the following syntax easiest to read:

```
insert  TargetTable
        (col1, col2)
from    SourceTable as source
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TargetTable as duplicate
        where   source.col1 = duplicate.col1
                and source.col2 = duplicate.col2
        )
```

Normally you don't have to worry about concurrency during a data migration.  If you do, you can specify locking hints like `with (tablock)` or a higher `transaction isolation level`.  Or you can use `merge` as suggested, but that has a rather convoluted syntax.

Answer (score 2):

SQL2003 defines [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), otherwise you can do an an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and in the `SELECT` you should `LEFT JOIN` in the destination table using the natural key in the `ON` predicate and then just chuck in a `WHERE <column> IS NULL`.

Comment: +1 but looks like the question has now been edited to refer to SQL Server 2005 rather than "standard SQL"

Comment: My answer is not SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from db1.schema1.table1
intersect 
select * from db2.schema2.table2
```